# Laravel redirect to other pages after successfull login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have three different types of users in my users table and after each success full login each specific type of user needs to be redirected to specific page according to role assigned in user table I read the documentation and tried different methods like `redirectTo` and protected properties. But they did not work for me.

If any one have a better solution to come up with this problem please share.

Note : please do not give route solutions.

Comment: Does any redirection works for you?

Comment: nope i tried to handle it with this method https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#login-throttling    but failed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Laravel 5.3 you can override `authenticated()` method in `LoginController.php`. For example:

```
protected function authenticated()
{
    if (auth()->user()->type === 1) {
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    } elseif (auth()->user()->type === 2) {
        return redirect()->route('client.dashboard');
    }
}
```